# MSSQL 2008 full-text search: does stemming take grammatical gender into account?

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search, stemming

We're using SQL Server 2008's full-text search to let customers retrieve records using `FREETEXTTABLE()` queries.

Given a search like:

```
SELECT * FROM FREETEXTTABLE(SomeTable, SomeValueColumn, 'Kunde')
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM FREETEXTTABLE(SomeTable, SomeValueColumn, 'Leser')
```

(German words for 'customer' and 'reader', respectively.)

, I would expect results for the feminine forms of those words as well. However, those results only appear if I explicitly search for 'Kundin' or 'Leserin'.

The server's default full-text language is `1031` (i.e., German). The language component is `NaturalLanguage6.dll`, version `6.0.6001.18000`.

[According to a book, this should work:](http://books.google.com/books?id=wGwVkAt79bEC&pg=PA106&lpg=PA106&dq=sql+stemming+gender&source=bl&ots=fveH95fo8e&sig=0DAjtJPQfVci6hAJfdglCGo7EwQ&hl=en&ei=-hraTdfMCIuVswb07Oj3Ag&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=sql%20stemming%20gender&f=false)

> SQL Server iFTS automatically includes stemming logic that accommodates gender rules for other languages [..]

Is this supposed to work? If not, can I make it work by A) installing an additional / different language component, or B) using a different full-text engine (e.g., Lucene.NET)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the discrepency is due to the fact that your first link above was written prior to the release of SQL 2008.  The second link is a book written explicitly for SQL 2008.

Re-read the complete chapter in the SQL 2008 FTS book, as there are several steps you have to take in order to get it to work.  Namely, identifying the language in your query.

Note this code block from page 116 of the book (which is using German as an example):

```
WHERE FREETEXT
(
  *, N'gift', LANGUAGE 1031
)
```

Here is the BOOKS ONLINE link (note Langugage argument):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx

Comment: You're right; the article refers to SQL Server 2000 and 2005. However, explicitly specifying `LANGUAGE 1031` is neither necessary [according to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177652.aspx) ("If no value is specified, the column full-text language is used."), nor did it help when I tried.

Comment: What is the datatype of the column(s) you're searching? nvarchar, varbinary, xml?

Comment: In addition to my above question... did you rebuild the index after applying the Language to the column (or specifying it in the query)?  If not, you'll have to.  Each FTS can only support ONE langugage and it cannot be changed after creation.

Comment: `varchar(max)`. If by rebuilding the index you mean rebuilding the catalog, the language never changed, but I just did anyway (to no avail).

Comment: Hmmm, don't know... if you have verified that the column really is set for German.  SELECT * FROM sys.fulltext_index_columns;  And the SQL Server has the German catalog installed (which it should by default), then I'm running out of ideas.  Sorry.

Comment: I don't know german, but varchar(max) should be fine unless german has accented, or non english letters, characters then you'd have to use nvarchar(max).